# cURL setopt CONNECTTIMEOUT vs TIMEOUT

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

After a lookup both on SO and other places, I've noticed there is a lot of conflicting information about the cURL options CONNECTTIMEOUT vs TIMEOUT.

CONNECTTIMEOUT is definitely the timeout just for the connection phase,

TIMEOUT is stated as being timeout for the entire cURL process (including CONNECTTIMEOUT) or the timeout after the connection phase has finished, depending on who you ask.

Furthermore, the official libcurl docs explain CONNECTTIMEOUT as

> set maximum time the request is allowed to take

which is quite ambiguous language as it could be referring to e.g a HTTP request or speaking about the entire process as a request

Answer (score 1):

CONNECTTIMEOUT is the time curl waits for during the connection. after that curl abandons the effort to connect. on the other hand, TIMEOUT is the total duration of receiving a response for a given request for which curl will wait, including the time it takes to connect and the time that the server takes to reply. here is the official link for both:

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.html

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html

Comment: I'm really unsure on this. There are various occasions where the time from trying to connect -> connected -> doing transfer -> timeout is higher than TIMEOUT. Unsure if it's TIMEOUT + CONNECTTIMEOUT, though. Seems to be more at work